# Ubuntu 14.10 x32 Nvidia Screen Resoulution Problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, monitor, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 32bit System. After Installing `Nvidia 340 Driver` for `Nvidia Geforce 6150se nforce 430` my system is working fine, but there is little problem my screen is not full, left and right side some empty blank space showing.I've a problem with my screen resolution and I am using `Samsung SA10 Monitor`. any suggestion how can I fix my Resolution?

Answer (score 0):

As per your [Monitor's manual](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/LS19A10NS/ZA#) you need to hold the power button for 5 seconds and use the "auto adjust"...

Low quality reviewers: another complex problem solved by a simple solution.  ;-)